# Change the timespan millisecond separator; comma(,) instead of dot(.)

Tags: c#, localization, cultureinfo, timespan, .net-4.6

I want to output a timespan in the local culture, to import it as csv in Excel.
The timespan contains milliseconds.

with the english culture, this means e.g. `00:00:01.2345678`
with the german culture, this should be `00:00:01,2345678` (comma instead of dot)

But no matter which settings i try for the CultureInfo object, I cannot get it to work:

```
TimeSpan t = new TimeSpan(12345678);
var cul = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de");
// cul.DateTimeFormat.FullTimeSpanPositivePattern == "d':'h':'mm':'ss','FFFFFFF";
// (note the comma)

Console.WriteLine(String.Format(cul, "{0}", t));
// expected: "00:00:01,2345678" (with ,)
// actual: "00:00:01.2345678" (with .)
```

So far, I cannot even tell which of the properties of the CultureInfo class defines this. Is this hardcoded somewhere?

I know I can explicitely define the output format: `String.Format("{0:hh\:mm\:ss\,FFFFFFF}", t)

But is there a way to use a `IFormatProvider` for this, so that c# will use the given Culture?

Comment: Have you tried `t.ToString("G",cul)` ? And "de-DE" ? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_TimeSpan_ToString_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_

Comment: @DavidG: that is about `DateTime.ToString`, this is about `TimeSpan.ToString`

Comment: @TimSchmelter Are you sure? the title suggests otherwise.

Comment: @Fildor: nice catch, the ["g" format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-timespan-format-strings#the-general-short-g-format-specifier) seems to do the trick.

Comment: @Fildor Look at the title of the question, and the MSDN link, both are for `TimeSpan`. The answer by Hans takes a TimsSpan, converts to DateTime and then outputs a string as a workaround.

Comment: @DavidG Yes. The Dupe you suggested was about DateTime, though. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Fildor I'm talking about the dupe, it's about formatting a TimeSpan

Comment: @DavidG OH, sorry. I take everything back I said. It is indeed about TimeSpan but uses DateTime as a workaround, yes. Wow I was really too superficial while reading.

Comment: @Fildor Thanks god, I thought I was going loop with both you and Tim saying otherwise. I'll hammer it then...

Comment: @DavidG: maybe you're right. But then the difference is that the other questions wants the hour,minute and second potions culture aware and there are no milliseconds. He even used `g`(which works here) but that didn't work for the h,m,s separator. The other question's title is too general

Comment: @DavidG I am afraid both of you are right: It _is_ about TimeSpan, but not really a dupe for this one.

Comment: @DavidG: fixed the title of the other question, still a duplicate compared to this title?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the ["g"-format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-timespan-format-strings#the-general-short-g-format-specifier), so `t.ToString("g", culture)`. By default a `TimeSpan` is converted using the `"c"`-format specifier, which is a common non-culture specific format.

Using `string.Format` this would be

```
String.Format(cul, "{0:g}", t)
```

More info on formatting timespans [can be found in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_TimeSpan_ToString_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_)

Answer (score 2):

This works for me. [Version fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/99jj9K)

```
TimeSpan t = new TimeSpan(12345678);
var cul = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de");
Console.WriteLine(t.ToString("g", cul));
```

The [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-timespan-format-strings) Microsoft said

> "g" : This specifier outputs only what is needed. It is
>   culture-sensitive and takes the form [-][d’:’]h’:’mm’:’ss[.FFFFFFF].